# Should I repair my items before I sell them?

Tags: diablo-iii

Found and bought items always start with a full durability, but sometimes I want to sell and item I have already used for a while and is not fully repaired.

For maximizing money gained, should I repair the item first, sell it without repairing, or does it yield the same total gold in both cases?

Comment: A side note, to sell them on AH they have to be fully repaired.

Comment: Why don't you try instead of asking?

Comment: Yeah, do some science!

Comment: Just log into the game and figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Repairing an item gets you no extra gold.

I just tested this myself.  Boots that sold for 53 gold and had only 80% durability were then repaired for 4 gold.  They were still selling for 53 gold after the repairing.

Comment: For science! :)

Comment: @Holger, but the cake is a lie!